# Infinite derivatives of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Derived from Cauchy's integral formula we know that

> If $f(z)$ is defined and analytic in open set $D\subset \Bbb C$ then $f(z)$ is differential infinite time in $D$

So what happen to functions like $\log$ and $n$-th root around $0$? there is a "line" with discontinuity in $D$

For example:  $f(z)=z^{\frac{4}{3}}$

Comment: What is your open set $D$ in each example where $f$ is analytic resp. holomorphic? There can be no ""line" with discontinuity" in $D$, you would have to reduce any such initial set by those points of discontinuity.

Comment: @LutzL let say a ball around $0$

Comment: There is no disk around $0$ where these functions are continuous everywhere. Even if you remove $0$ from the disk. As you already observed. There is no solution to an impossible situation.

Comment: Your quoted theorem requires $f(z)$ to be "defined and analytic".  So study whether $z^{4/3}$ is defined and analytic.